# One button -- 3 App stores -- how to redirect the user to the appropriate appstore?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, windows-phone-8

I am wanting to create a simple button which redirects mobile users to the appropriate app store link depending on which mobile os they are running (ios, android or wp8) - or if not on a mobile then offers to send an email containing the appropriate link...Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well... This is actually pretty straightforward. To begin with, you must detect the device the user is currently using by means of their user agent string. And then use jQuery to simply set the `href` attribute of the anchor element correctly. The following code illustrates.

```
var operatingSystem, userAgentString = navigator.userAgent;
var link = $("#store");

if (userAgentString.indexOf("iPhone") > -1 || userAgentString.indexOf("iPod") > -1 || userAgentString.indexOf("iPad") > -1) {
    operatingSystem = "iOS";
    link.attr("href", "http://store.apple.com/us/browse/app");
} else if (/Android/.test(userAgentString)) {
    operatingSystem = "Android";
    link.attr("href", "https://play.google.com/store/apps?hl=en");
} else if (/Windows Phone/.test(userAgentString)) {
    operatingSystem = "Windows Phone";
    link.attr("href", "http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5g0zqm0s/

Comment: Thank you so much. I completely forgot I had posted this question (working on other things) then started wondering how to go about this task and remembered....i wasn't ignoring you!!

Thanks!! :D

Comment: You'll have to check for windows phone first, because recent windows phone user agents contain "Android" and "iPhone", e.g. `Mozilla/5.0 (Mobile; Windows Phone 8.1; Android 4.0; ARM; Trident/7.0; Touch; rv:11.0; IEMobile/11.0; Microsoft; Lumia 640 LTE) like iPhone OS 7_0_3 Mac OS X AppleWebKit/537 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537`

Answer (score 0):

Check the user agent to determine what OS is being run and based on result route link appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Using php, you can detect which mobile device the user is on. There are several plugins for this. You could then echo out the href of the link accordingly. Sorry, cant comment. Spent too much bounty!